# Ionic Grid Layout with ng-repeat ionic

Tags: angularjs, grid, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

Can someone help me to create rows with varied number of columns using single ng-repeat on a template?

For example,
row 0- with 3 columns
row 1 -with 2 columns
row 2-with 1 column.

And, as the number of columns change ,the displayed column(s) should automatically stretch to occupy the full row space.

I have implemented it with nested ng-repeat but then I'm not able to apply ngFx animations to it.So, I'd like to try with single ng-repeat.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you ! wink

I had the idea of using ng-if on a column element but not sure if it's the efficient considering performance.

Comment: I wouldn't use ng-if on the column, I would use it on the row.  I dont know your exact use scenario so this might not be realistic.  But I would have all the possible rows built out (1, 2, 3, 4 column.. etc...) and ng-if on the rows.  Can you add a fiddle with an example?

Comment: [ http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/OPWyZd ] @JacobCarter How to make rows with different number of columns? using ng-if doesn't really help as I ran into trouble with index then.

Comment: I should have also mentioned, I would do this with row and column DIVs not an actual table

Comment: Okay your codepen shed some light on the situation, with Ionic CSS you can just label the class col and it will automatically fit everything into a grid, this will only work for one row however, So the problem is that you would need to created a new row when necessary.  How flexible is your `$scope.cards` array? Can you change the format of this? If so let me know and I can code up an example